# move sematics in thread wrapper class with RAII in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, move, most-vexing-parse

I am trying to get a RAII wrapper class around std::thread to work in C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

void threadFunction()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        cout << "thread function pointer executing..." << i << endl;
    }
}



// RAII wrapper that supports automatic join
class ThreadJoinRAII
{
    std::thread thread_;
public:
    ThreadJoinRAII(std::thread&& t):thread_(std::move(t)) 
    // ThreadJoinRAII()
    {
        cout << "ThreadJoinRAII ctor" << endl;
    }

    //ThreadJoinRAII(const ThreadJoinRAII& other) = delete;
    //ThreadJoinRAII& operator=(const ThreadJoinRAII& other) = delete;

    //ThreadJoinRAII(ThreadJoinRAII&& other):thread_(std::move(other.thread_))
    //{
    //    cout << "ThreadJoinRAII move ctor" << endl;
    //}
    //ThreadJoinRAII& operator=(ThreadJoinRAII&& other)
    //{
    //    cout << "ThreadJoinRAII move op" << endl;
    //    thread_ = std::move(other.thread_);
    //    return *this;
    //}
    
    ~ThreadJoinRAII()
    {
        cout << "in ThreadJoinRAII dtor" << endl;
        if (thread_.joinable()) { 
            thread_.join();
            cout << "join thread id = " << thread_.get_id() << endl;
        } else {
            cout << "thread not joinable. id=" << thread_.get_id() << endl;
        }
    }
};

class Something
{
    std::vector<int> vec_;
public:
    Something(std::vector<int>&& v):vec_(std::move(v)) {
        cout << "Something ctor" << endl;
    }

};


void testRAII()
{
    ThreadJoinRAII t1(std::move(std::thread(threadFunction))); // prints ThreadJoinRAII ctor
    ThreadJoinRAII t2(std::thread(threadFunction)); // prints nothing
    Something s1(std::vector<int>(3, 4)); // prints Something ctor
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testRAII();
    return 0;
}
```

The issue is that `t2` line in `testRAII()` prints nothing. That part I don't understand. I tried to add/remove copy operations and move operations and they didn't make any difference.

My questions are:

1. Isn't `std::thread(threadFunction)` is already a rvalue in `testRAII()`? Why do I have to move it for the constructor to work?
2. What code gets invoked for `t2` if the constructor provided was not used? I don't see ThreadJoinRAII ctor printed.
3. `s1` line prints out "Something ctor". What is the difference between `t2` and `s1`? Is `std::thread` rvalue treated differently?

BTW, I compiled the code on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with g++ 9.3 with `g++ -std=c++17 -o mt mt.m.cpp -lpthread`. `mt.m.cpp` is my file name.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but you should mark single argument constructors as `explicit`

Comment: @AlanBirtles Is this a general recommendation for that? I know I have ran into situation where explicit saved me. For example when I define `operator bool() const` functions.

Comment: Yes, it's not always necessary but doesn't usually do any harm so is a good habit to get into. A RAII type class is especially critical as an accidental conversion will result in the contained class getting destroyed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may not look like it at first glance, but `t2` is a function prototype, not a variable declaration (search for "most vexing parse").

You can change it to a variable by adding some parentheses:

```
ThreadJoinRAII t2((std::thread(threadFunction)));
```

then it will call your `ThreadJoinRAII` constructor.

Comment: Or use the curly brace version: `ThreadJoinRAII t2{std::thread(threadFunction)};`

Comment: Thank you. So this is the example from wikipedia `TimeKeeper time_keeper(Timer());` and it is interrupted as `(void -> Timer) -> TimeKeeper` which makes sense. So in this case, I guess it is `(threadFunction -> std::thread) -> ThreadJoinRAII`. How can `threadFunction` be a type?

Comment: @dhu `threadFunction` isn't a type. It is the parameter name (just like in `ThreadJoinRAII t2(std::thread threadFunction);`). The wiki example does not have a parameter name.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm So in this case what is the type of the parameter name `threadFunction`? I believe I ran into a most vexing parse case but I don't think I fully understood why and how.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm I guess I misunderstood your statement. I think you meant `t2` is of type `std::thread -> ThreadJoinRAII`. But that's even more confusing to me. What If I had `ThreadJoinRAII t2(std::thread(int))`. I guess now I have `(int -> std::thread) -> ThreadJoinRAII`? So since `threadFunction` is not a unknown type, it is a parameter name?

Comment: @dhu `threadFunction` is of type `std::thread`. This is just like any function prototype or declaration: the parameter declaration consists of a type an optional parameter name.